# How to use “textaInit” function in “mscstexta4r” package for Microsoft Cognitive Services?

Tags: r, azure-cognitive-services

I am using “mscstexta4r” package for sentimental analysis. It is mentioned to run textaInit() before using the core functions. I am not able to figure out how to use , i have tried to use it as mentioned, in the code below(example code mentioned for the package) but it returns an error.

```
library(mscstexta4r)
#MSCS_TEXTANALYTICS_URL = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment' (Set in Sys.setenv())
#MSCS_TEXTANALYTICS_KEY='XXXX'(Set in Sys.setenv())

textaInit()

docsText <- c(
  "Loved the food, service and atmosphere! We'll definitely be back."

)
docsLanguage <- rep("en", length(docsText))
tryCatch({
  # Perform sentiment analysis
  docsSentiment <- textaSentiment(
    documents = docsText, # Input sentences or documents
    languages = docsLanguage
    # "en"(English, default)|"es"(Spanish)|"fr"(French)|"pt"(Portuguese)
  )
  class(docsSentiment)
  str(docsSentiment, max.level = 1)
  docsSentiment

}, error = function(err) {
  geterrmessage()
})
```

Error :

```
"Error: mscstexta4r: Not Found (HTTP 404). - { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }"
```

.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Per the package documentation, the MSCS Text Analysis endpoint base URL is:

"https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/texta/analytics/v2.0/"

It is not:

"https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/texta/analytics/v2.0/sentiment"

mscstexta4r will add the proper verb based on which API function you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Be sure to use the following URL in the .json configuration file:
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/

I was using R Studio.  I needed to clear the objects before succeeding in the calls.  Yo do that in the right panel of R Studio 8 (The broom icon).

Comment: I tried clearing the objects , including hidden objects, it worked well(Last time i defined the variables in R but this time i did that in R Studio itself).